# SilverStripe MultiForm not working

Tags: php, registration, silverstripe, add-on

I installed and configured SilverStripe on my server. I installed the [MultiForm module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-multiform) and followed the instructions in the module documentation.

After following the instructions I still don't see any new page type in my CMS Portal.

I also tried `db/build?flush=1` & `dev/build?flush=1` but it doesn't make a difference.

I Created the Following files in `mysite/code/` directory

**SponsorSignupForms.php**

```
class SponsorSignupForms extends MultiForm{
    protected static $start_step = 'CompanyDetailsStep';
}
```

**CompanyDetailsStep.php**

```
class CompanyDetailsStep extends MultiFormStep{
    public static $next_steps = 'ContactDetailsStep';
    function getFields()
    {
        $fields = singleton('Member')->getFrontendFields();
        return $fields;
    }
    function getValidator()
    {
        return new Member_Validator('FirstName', 'Surname', 'Email', 'Password');
    }
}
```

**ContactDetailsStep.php**

```
class ContactDetailsStep extends MultiFormStep{
    public static $is_final_step = true;
    function getFields()
    {
        $fields = singleton('Reference')->getFrontendFields();
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

How do I get these custom MultiForms working and appearing as creatable pages?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using SilverStripe 3.1. Note in 3.1 `db/build?flush=1` won't do anything. `dev/build?flush=1` should build any database changes for you. When you call `dev/build?flush=1` do you see the "Environment Builder" screen?

Comment: @3dgoo `dev/build?flush=1` in this screen i found my pages `ContactDetailsStep` and `CompanyDetailsStep` and `SponsorSignupForms`, But it doesn't shown in Page types, Thanks for edit

Comment: @3dgoo Yes, im using silverstripe 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you don't see any new page type in the list of available pages, you will only see subclasses of `SiteTree` there, `MultiFormStep` is "just" a subclass of `DataObject`.

You can plug your form to every page you want manually, but you also can create a new page type for your form and include the Form in your Controller and Template, see [readme of MultiForm](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-multiform#5-run-database-integrity-check):

```
class MyFormPage extends Page
{
}

class MyFormPageController extends Page_Controller
{
    // 
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'SponsorSignupForms',
        'finished'
    );

    public function SponsorSignupForms() {
        return new SponsorSignupForms($this, 'Form');
    }

    public function finished() {
        return array(
            'Title' => 'Thank you for your submission',
            'Content' => '<p>You have successfully submitted the form!</p>'
        );
    }
}
```

In the template just include the form:

```
<% if $SponsorSignupForms %>
    $SponsorSignupForms
<% end_if %>
```

and you should see the form now.

Comment: I checked the read me and my team member configured/ installed it incorrectly so it is not showing, thank you